# Fire a jquery plugins function in ajax done portion

Tags: jquery

I am using a table filter plugin which working just fine but after a AJAXcall when I load certain portion of the page and then call the plugin function in AJAX done method. But this time its not working. I have to reload the page to again get the plugins functionality.

function on page load

```
(function($) {
    $('#studentTable').ddTableFilter();
})(jQuery);
```

Function in AJAX Done method

```
.done(function() {
    var currentPageUrl = window.location.href;
    $('.student_list').load(currentPageUrl + ' .student_list');
    $('#studentTable').ddTableFilter();
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `var currentPageUrl = window.location.href;
    $('.student_list').load(currentPageUrl + ' .student_list');` ?

Comment: This portion contain the table and after I update one of the table row. I just reload this potion to get instant update in view.

Comment: If table row is updated why does remainder of table that is not changed need to be updated ? Does `$('.student_list').load(currentPageUrl + ' .student_list');` load same element into itself ? creating `.student_list .student_list` ?

Comment: I edit a value in the DB from where the table is being fetched. But in the above code i refreshed the student_list portion so that the edited db could also be shown in view also